# Generating sea bed depths in 2D map

Tags: c#, 2d, monogame, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

I have a 2D tile map of 100x100 tiles. Most of them are sea tiles and a island in the middle. I want each of the sea tiles to have a depth value.

I have thought about using something like a noise map to generate a terrain, and then turning it upside down, but I'm unsure how to take the already existing land into account. Because the depth is shallower the closer to land you get.

I must note that the island in the middle is designed and not generated layout.

So basically what I want is to generate a map that looks something like this, where 0 is flat land and the other values are depths in meters f.ex.

```
9 9 9 9 9 8 9 8 7
9 7 7 8 7 6 7 6 6
9 7 4 3 3 3 4 5 6
9 6 2 0 0 0 0 3 6
9 6 2 0 0 0 0 1 6
9 6 2 0 0 0 0 3 6
9 7 4 2 2 2 1 3 6
9 7 7 8 7 6 7 6 6
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: A 2d gaussian distribution has more or less this shape.

Comment: Another method would be to use standard perlin noise (tutorials everywhere), and filter the output adding a negative bias the further away you are from the center. You could adjust the bias to generate larger islands, or deeper waters.

Answer (score 1):

Use Perlin Noise and increase the values near where you want the island by some factor like 1.2 (or lower all other values).

Improved noise: https://gist.github.com/Flafla2/1a0b9ebef678bbce3215

I recommend you add turbulence for nicer results: http://paulbourke.net/fractals/perlin/

Then to take into account the existing land, you can average the noise with your existing model (and exclude some above water values from it).